# linked list in c++ without classes: segmentation fault

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, structure

I'm trying code a simple homework at school and get the error *Segmentation fault (core dumped)* implementing a linked list in C++ in this way:

```
struct Word{
    string word;
    string meaning;
    Word * next;
};

struct dictionary{
    Word *head = NULL;
    int count;
}dict;

string addWord(string word, string meaning){
    Word *newWord = new Word;
    newWord -> word = word;
    newWord -> meaning = meaning;
    newWord -> next = dict.head;
    dict.head = newWord;
    dict.count++; 
}
```

I'm trying to add a word (node) when get the error, I can't use c++ class because is a requieriment of a teacher, sincery thank for you help!

Comment: Did you mean to not return anything from addWord?

Comment: All of this code looks fine. Perhaps there is some more code that might be causing a problem?

Comment: Where is `dict` being instantiated, which you are using in this statement `newWord -> next = dict.head;`? I just see the declaration.

Comment: Not, I just noticed that the title is  wrong, I mean that when call addWord("example","example"); y get a segmentation fault error and I dont understand why.

Comment: You're getting a core dump. You should debug it instead of just assuming it's this code. It looks OK at first glance, without seeing the rest of the context.

Comment: @YogendraSingh, It's created when the class is defined. On another note, this has no hope at all of compiling in C.

Comment: @Yogendra maybe you have reason, but how I should instiate? I try dictioary dict = new dictionary; and get: error: conversion from ‘dictionary*’ to non-scalar type ‘dictionary’ requested and dict = NULL y get segmentation fault again :(

Comment: @ldav1s there is not more code different to int main(){
    addWord("example","example");
    return 0;
}

Comment: @tjameson I had not understood what you were saying, but you were right, thank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dict.count` is never initialized.  Given that your compiler can include default initializations in a `struct` definition, you should write `int count = 0;` where it is defined.  This is not causing your segfault, probably, but you still need to fix it.

I suspect `addWord` failing to return a `string`, despite it having that as a return value, could be causing your segfault.  This results in undefined behavior (which could crash).  A compiler worth its salt would give you a fatal warning for writing the code you wrote.  Change the return type of `addWord` to `void`.   Like this:

```
void addWord(string word, string meaning)
```

General advice about posting problems on this website:

When you post problems, include everything that it needs for your code to compile and run, including a `main` method.  Remove anything you don't think is important from your code, but what you leave behind should still run, and should demonstrate your problem.

When you show code that is incomplete, you are being a fool: if you knew what was important, you wouldn't need to ask for help, would you?  So you need to post complete code.

When you show too much code, you are being impolite.  First pare your code down to the minimal example that shows your problem, but leave it complete so we can see where your real problem is.

Comment: Thank, I will consider your recommendations, really I'm a fool the error was caused for missed a return :P